# nginx access control: some allowed freely, some with password, or denied

Tags: nginx

I want to make a kind of complex configuration for nginx:

- Basically all access from the Internet is denied (= `deny all;`)
- A network segment should be allowed to access freely (= `allow 10.0.1.0/24;`)
- Another network segment should be allowed to access, with basic auth (= `satisfy all; deny all; allow 10.0.2.0/24;`)

I want to write the configuration file like below, but of course it has an error, since `satisfy` can appear only once.

```
location / {
    satisfy any;
    allow 10.0.1.0/24;  # allowed to access freely
    deny all;
    satisfy all;  ### ERROR
    allow 10.0.2.0/24;  # allowed to access, with basic auth
    auth_basic           "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file "closed.htpasswd";
    # proxy to somewhere
    http://localhost:10081;
}
```

How can I achieve this requirement?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

self answer (partially)

I could accept to modify `server` directive configuration for this case, so the following configuration looks working

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # server directive allows only these two networks
    allow 10.0.1.0/24;
    allow 10.0.2.0/24;
    deny all;
    location / {
        satisfy any;
        # here comes the two networks above, so I can rely on "satisfy any"
        allow 10.0.1.0/24;
        deny all;
        auth_basic           "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file "closed.htpasswd";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:10081;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate there is more straightforward way.